# How to remove single and double quotes from a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

When I run a phrase that contains double quotes through this function, its replacing the quotes with quot.

I want to completely remove them (also single quotes). How can I alter the function to do that?

```
function string_sanitize($s) {
    $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $s);
    return $result;
}
```

Update:

```
Example 1: This is 'the' first example 
returns: Thisis030the039firstexample 
Errors: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '0' in C


Example 2: This is my "second" example
returns: Thisismyquotsecondquotexample
Errors: Invalid express in Xpath
```

Comment: This function already cuts out both `'` and `"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like your original string had the HTML characters for `"` (`&quot;`) so when you attempt to sanitize it, you're simply remove the `&` and `;`, leaving the rest of the string `quot`.

---EDIT---

Probably the easiest way to remove non alpha numeric characters would be to decode the HTML characters with [html_entity_decode](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), then run it through the regular expression. Since, in this case, you won't get anything that needs to be re-coded, you don't need to then do [htmlentities](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), but it's worth remembering that you *had* HTML data and you now have *raw unencoded* data.

Eg:

```
function string_sanitize($s) {
    $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES));
    return $result;
}
```

Note that `ENT_QUOTES` flags the function to  "...convert both double and single quotes.".

Comment: +1 great point and observation. Any idea how I can strip &quote; then?

Comment: Edited with an example of how you could do it.

Comment: You've just saved me a night of wasted effort. I appreciate it :-)

Comment: also, if you want to keep the spaces. add \s in the regex so it looks like "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/"

Answer (score 31):

I would not call that function `string_sanitize()`, as it is misleading. You could call it `strip_non_alphanumeric()`.

Your current function will strip anything that isn't an upper or lowercase letter or a number.

You can strip just `'` and `"` with...

```
$str = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $str);
```

Comment: Yes, it is very easy and nice solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your preg_replace call should be like this:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", html_entity_decode($s));
```

Please see [html_entity_decode reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses regular expression to remove any character that different from [a-zA-Z0-9], so it surely removes any "" or ''

EDIT: well, from Hamish answer I realize your string is a HTML string, so that it explain why "(&quot) to be transformed to "quot". You may consider replace `&quote` by preg_replace, or [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) first.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be sure of remove all kind of quotes (including those into which left side are different from the right side ones) I think it must be something like;

```
function string_sanitize($s) {
    $result = htmlentities($s);
    $result = preg_replace('/^(&quot;)(.*)(&quot;)$/', "$2", $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/^(&laquo;)(.*)(&raquo;)$/', "$2", $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/^(&#8220;)(.*)(&#8221;)$/', "$2", $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/^(&#39;)(.*)(&#39;)$/', "$2", $result);
    $result = html_entity_decode($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way for both single and double quotes : )
And still leaves something similar to look at.

```
$clean_string = str_replace('"', '``', str_replace("'", "`", $UserInput));
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. They want tp **remove** single and double quotes.

Comment: it removes and then adds an alternate - so it not only - does - answer the question, but it also helpfully adds something else for them to think about for their solution.