# PHP's how to trim quotes using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string

I just want to strip quotes (**at the beginning and the end**) from a string but would like to keep `"` or `'` in between. 
I have tried this.

```
preg_replace("/(^\')|(\'$)|(^")|("$)/", '', $str);
```

The function does not strip quotes.
Is there anything wrong with the regex?

**Besides substr()**, any other way to strip quotes?

Comment: Trim them, then add new ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454273/how-to-remove-single-and-double-quotes-from-a-string

Comment: no, this is not what I want. This simply remove all quote in a string.

Comment: trim($str, "\'")also didn't work.

Comment: Please show us your exact input sample.

Comment: If `$str = trim($str, "\"'");`doesn't work, then your string doesn't start or end with either double or single quotes. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I eventually find out that didn't work juz becoz of my careless mistake. I actually am working on csv data processing. I trimmed the entire line of files instead of item for columns as supposed. Trim() worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all the quotes at the beginning and at the end of the string, you might use:

[`^['"]*(.*?)['"]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/LXL0oh/1/)

**This would match**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a single quote or a double quote `['"]*` zero or more times
- Capture any character zero or more times non greedy `(.*?)` in a group
- Match a single quote or a double quote `['"]*` zero or more times
- The end of the string `$`

In the replacement, you can use group 1 `$1`

[Output example php](https://3v4l.org/8c0QR)

Using [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) with the characters you want to strip as the second parameter would give the [same output](https://3v4l.org/PEuh7).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to escape double quotes in your expression :

```
$str = "''this 'is' a \"test\" !''" ;
$str = preg_replace("/(^\')|(\'$)|(^\")|(\"$)/", '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Outputs :

```
string(23) "'this 'is' a "test" !'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to remove simple characters from the start and end of a string, the best way to remove them is use the [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) function, instead of a preg_replace:

```
$str = trim($str, "'\"");
```

If your string does not really start or end with a quote, but contains also an `\n` or `\r` or `\t` or `\0` or `vertical tab`, use that function twice to remove them first:

```
$str = trim(trim($str), "'\"");
```

From the [`Manual`](http://php.net/trim):

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
>
> Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:
>
> ```
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
> ```